# Attempting to run retabot.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord

All I get is the following:

```
module.js:540
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Peter\Downloads\EasyChanBot\retabot.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Any ideas?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the stack trace says

`Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Peter\Downloads\EasyChanBot\retabot.js'`

Check if the file retabot.js is in the directory and also check if you can open it.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to DobromirM's answer, also check if you refer to the file location correctly, maybe use something like `../folder/filename`